# How do I create a self-signed SSL certificate?

Tags: server, ssl

I've set up SSL on my webserver, now I need two files:

- a certificate
- a certificate Key

How do I create a self-signed certificate for testing purposes?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Ubuntu, even the 'minimal' flavour, comes with the `ssl-cert` package pre-installed, which means you don't need to do anything.

The files you're looking for are already on your system:

```
/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

**Advanced:**

If for some reason you need to create a fresh certificate, you can run

```
sudo make-ssl-cert generate-default-snakeoil --force-overwrite
```

If you want to change the expiration date of you certificate, you can manipulate the make-ssl-cert script at `/usr/sbin/make-ssl-cert`. Around like 124 there's a line similar to this:

```
openssl req -config $TMPFILE -new -x509 -nodes \
```

Where you can change the expiration date by adding the `-days` argument:

```
openssl req -config $TMPFILE -new -days 365 -x509 -nodes \
```

More options can be found in the [manual page of `req`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/req.1ssl.html).

Comment: ubuntu-server 12.04 ( AMI cloud image) doesn't have ssl-cert installed by default have it. But once ssl-cert is installed  - /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem becomes available automatically.

Comment: make-ssl-cert takes the key length (and other settings) to use from `/usr/share/ssl-cert/ssleay.cnf`.

Comment: In attempting to test a website in a local vagrant VM instance, I wanted to Google Chrome to act as if it was a totally normal certificate. I had to first set the VM's hostname to match the testing url (e.g. `www.test.mydomain.com`) using the `hostname` command in the VM CLI. Then regenerating the key as you suggest, with `--force-overwrite`, the key's Common Name (CN) then matched the testing url. Finally, on the host machine, installing the key as a Trusted Root Certificate Authority (in Chrome's Settings/Advanced) gave me the coveted green address bar.

Comment: my 9-year old cert stopped working with my upgrade to debian 10, so the `make-ssl-cert` command saved the day for me!

Comment: Also, nginx on ubuntu has `/etc/nginx/snippets/snakeoil.conf` that sets up paths to certificate files generated by `ssl-cert`.

Comment: In a ubuntu 16.04 server `make-ssl-cart` was not installed. so I installed it with this command: `$ sudo apt-get install -y ssl-cert`. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 24):

As already mentioned, Ubuntu Server comes with the necessary tools. Depending on your server version you'll have to look up the [specific documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com). I'll try to summarize the self-signed certificate generation process of [the current LTS (12.04)](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/certificates-and-security.html).

First you generate the keys for the Certificate Signing Request (CSR):

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 2048
```

It's up to you to enter a passphrase or not. If you do, everytime you (re)start a service usign that certificate, you'll have to provide the passphrase. Otoh you can create an "insecure" key without a passphrase from the secure one:

```
openssl rsa -in server.key -out server.key.insecure
# shuffle the key names to continue without passphrases
mv server.key server.key.secure
mv server.key.insecure server.key
```

And now you'll create the CSR from the key. With the CSR and the key a self-signed certificate can be generated:

```
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
```

The last step consists of installing the certificate and the key, in Debian/Ubuntu usually in `/etc/ssl`:

```
sudo cp server.crt /etc/ssl/certs
sudo cp server.key /etc/ssl/private
```

And finally the applications using the certificate/key have to be configured accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are good, but if for some reason you dont have the listed
tools, or dont want to use them, I found an open source tool that is very
simple:

```
minica -domains localhost
```

This will create key file `minica-key.pem` and cert file `minica.pem`. The tool
for creating these is just a single file in the Go language, with no external
dependencies:

https://github.com/jsha/minica